# identify if two or more elements in sequence have same property

Tags: c#

I want to identify and extract the elements if two or more elements in sequence have same property inside a list.
e.g. 
i have a List
there is a property for document called Isvalid
now i want to identify if two or more documents in sequence have IsValid == true
suppose the structure is

```
IsValid = false
IsValid = true
IsValid = true
IsValid = false
IsValid = true
IsValid = false
```

My query should return only elements 2 and 3 beccause only these two are in sequence and have ISvalid = true
how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple LINQ extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>
    ContinuouslyEqualSubSequences<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TResult> func
) {
    var e = source.GetEnumerator();
    var currentSequence = default(List<TSource>);
    var resultOfCurrentSequence = default(TResult);
    if (e.MoveNext()) {
        currentSequence = new List<TSource>() { e.Current };
        resultOfCurrentSequence = func(e.Current);
     }
     while (e.MoveNext()) {
         var currentResult = func(e.Current);
         if(Object.Equals(resultOfCurrentSequence, currentResult)) {
             currentSequence.Add(e.Current);
         }
         else {
             if(currentSequence.Count > 1) {
                 yield return currentSequence;
             }
             currentSequence = new List<TSource>() { e.Current };
             resultOfCurrentSequence = currentResult;
          }
      }

      if (currentSequence.Count > 1) {
          yield return currentSequence;
      }
   }
```

On

```
var sequence = new { 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 1, 17, 2, 3, 2, 20 };
var subsequences = sequence.ContinuouslyEqualSubSequences(x => x % 2);
```

I get back the sequences

```
2 4 6 0
1 1 17
2 20
```

as expected since we're looking here for continuous subsequences of odd or even numbers.

Comment: Wow. Your definition of "simple" is clearly quite different from mine!

Comment: Don't conflate length with non-simple. This algorithm *is* simple. Read from the sequence, keeping track of the current "projection" (I called it `resultOfCurrentSequence`). For each subsequent item that you encounter with the same projection, add it to the current subsequence (I called it `currentSequence`). When you encounter something different, yield the current subsequence if it has length more than one, start a new subsequence and replace the old projection with the new projection . If get to the end of the sequence, and the length of current subsequence is more than one, yield it back.

Comment: I'm not saying that your *algorithm* isn't simple, just that the code isn't (and I'm not saying there's anything wrong with your code). In 22 lines it contains 14 calls to constructors, methods, and properties, plus 4 `if`s and a `while` -- and that's ignoring the missing `using` to dispose of the enumerator. Also, returning a sequence of sequences is not as simple as just returning a flattened sequence. My solution is several lines shorter with no constructor/method/property calls, and it's still not quite what I would consider "simple".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the current item is valid and if the previous item is valid at the same time. This will catch most cases, though you'll need to make sure you preserve the previous item if it hasn't been stored already.

Something like the code below should do. Note that it's written from memory, untested, and my not be the most efficient approach.

```
public List<Document> GetConsecutiveTrueDocs(List<Document> list)
{
    var result = new List<Document>();

    if(list.Count < 2)
        return result;

    for(int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if(list[i].IsValid && list[i-1].IsValid)
        {
            if(!result.Contains(list[i-1]))
                result.Add(list[i-1]);

            result.Add(list[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively simple extension method that takes a source sequence and a function that tells whether any two elements are considered equal, and returns a single sequence of elements:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Consecutives<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                             Func<T, T, bool> equals)
{
    T last = default(T);
    bool first = true;
    bool returnedLast = false;
    foreach (T current in source)
    {
        if (!first && equals(current, last))
        {
            if (!returnedLast)
                yield return last;
            returnedLast = true;
            yield return current;
        }
        else
            returnedLast = false;
        first = false;
        last = current;
    }
}
```

If you try it with

```
var sequence = new[] { 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 1, 17, 2, 3, 2, 20 };
var subsequences = sequence.Consecutives((x, y) => x % 2 == y % 2);
```

You'll get back:
`2
4
6
0
1
1
17
2
20`

If your sequence doesn't have any duplicates, this expansion of Raymond's solution is inefficient, but very simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Consecutives<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                             Func<T, T, bool> equals)
{
    return source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (x, y) => new[] { x, y })
                 .Where(d => equals(d[0], d[1]))
                 .SelectMany(d => d)
                 .Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be reduced to a one-liner by zipping the sequence with an offset version of itself.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TSource,TSource>>
    Consecutives<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                          Func<TSource, TSource, bool> equals)
{
    return source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x,y))
                 .Where(d => equals(d.Item1, d.Item2));
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants an `IEnumerable<TSource>` as a result, and it's not clear how to get that from your function's `IEnumerable<Tuple<TSource,TSource>>`.

Comment: It wasn't clear what the OP wanted if there were three true items in a row. Did they want (2, 3, 3, 4) or just (2, 3, 4)? For the former, do a SelectMany. For the latter, add a Unique.

Comment: OK, but `SelectMany` on a `Tuple` doesn't make sense. Maybe you want an array?

Comment: Right. I was giving a solution pattern, not an answer.